# Team Members Unable to View Work Item Templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am relatively new to Azure DevOps, so hopefully what I am about to ask makes sense...

My company utilizes a custom version of the Agile template for our projects. My particular project contains two different teams.

I am a member of the first team for visibility purposes. I manage the second team and would like to grant them the ability to use the work item templates I created.

Unfortunately, they are not able to see or use my templates and I am not sure why. The Azure DevOps documentation says they must 1) be members of the Azure DevOps team and 2) be members of the Contributor group. I can confirm both of those boxes are checked, but no dice.

My knowledge of Azure DevOps permissions is admittedly very little and my Google searches have yielded no promising results. Has anyone run into this problem before and know what the solution might be? Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

[Request #1: Sam's View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68TRu.jpg)

[Request #1: Tyler's View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxqRa.jpg)

[Request #1: Tyler's View Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R539.jpg)

[Request #2: Sam's View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mshmt.jpg)

[Request #2: Tyler's View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o42ay.jpg)

[Request #3: IS Team Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LpBc.jpg)

[Request #3: IS Team Members](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nHx6.jpg)

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue? If you still occurs this issue, could you share some screenshots of the team member and work item Templates page here? In addition, please also confirm that these team member can view the Templates page and create new templates.

Comment: My apologies for the delay here! I added the screenshots you requested. I provided two sets, one for myself (Sam) and another for my team member (Tyler). My security settings display differently than how you described them in request #3. I grabbed what I could though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for the permissions granted in permissions tab
2. Verify the other team members have the same process template - Agile/ Basic

Comment: I can confirm the individuals experiencing the issue are part of the correct team and members of the Contributors group. I can also confirm they have the same process template.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I created two teams, `test` and `Test_Agile Team` and created different templates for the two teams, you could check the pic below.

[image]

Then I added a user to `Test_Agile Team` and `Contributor` group, then try to create work item with template.

Result:

We can create work items via `Test_Agile Team` work item template. Please check the pic.

[image]

You need open project settings->teams->select one team and ensure these users are in this team.

Open project setting->Team configuration->switch to team->click the tab Templates->select the work item and ensure that there have template.

**Update1**

Please contact team members and share the following screenshots here.

1. open project settings->Team configuration->switch to the correct team->click the tab Templates->select the work item type that has the template such as below.

If see the error `You do not have permission to edit templates for this team`, the user will not see the work item template and use it in the Boards section. you need open project settings->Teams->click the correct team and ensure the user is a member of this team.

[image]

2. Open work item->Template->Capture and then then share the screenshot here.

[image]

3. Open project settings->Permissions->Click the tab Users->select the user and then share the permission screenshot here.

Comment: I double-checked the configuration you outlined. Unfortunately, it did not solve my issue. Could this be related to permissions or how my security groups are set up? Please let me know what screenshots I can provide to better assist.

Comment: Hi @SamMorgan, I have updated the answer, please check the update1 and then share the screenshots here. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: My apologies for the delay here! I added the screenshots you requested. I provided two sets, one for myself (Sam) and another for my team member (Tyler). My security settings display differently than how you described them in request #3. I grabbed what I could though.

Comment: I wanted to follow up here and see if you got a chance to review the linked screenshots?